# Howler.js variable offset

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-audio-api, howler.js

I transitioned from Web Audio API to Howler.js for the convenience it offers, however I can't figure out how to implement a variable (silenced) offset at the beginning of the sound.

---

Here's an example:

Let `snd` be a simple Howl sound and `offset` be a variable number:

```js
let snd = new Howl({ src: data })
let offset = 2000 // in ms
```

I want to be able to something along the lines of:

```js
snd.seek(1000)
```

and that would not seek 1 second into the sound but rather halfway in the start offset.

Also, if `snd` is playing, I need to be able to do the following:

```js
offset = 4000
```

and the audio would be moved 2 seconds further (4000ms - 2000ms) during playback.

---

Obviously, the example is oversimplified and the assignment of the offset would be in a function with a bunch of other logic. That being said, is there any way to achieve this with Howler.js, even if a bit hacky ?

I've seen options with timers and `setTimeout` but these seem either inaccurate or incompatible with my logic requirements. I've also tried negative values for `seek()` but these seem to get defaulted to `0`.

Comment: It's really difficult to figure out what you want here. Why would you want `seek(1000)` to somehow actually do `seek(offset / 2)`? Or are you trying to simply _advance_ the play position relative to the current play position? Can you be more specific here?

Comment: Sorry, maybe bad choice of wording there. I said halfway because `seek(1000)` would lead to half of the `offset` which is from 0 to 2000ms.

Comment: In other words, I basically want the functions (like `seek`, `play`, `pause`, etc.) to behave just as they'd normally do if the source sound had `offset` milliseconds of nothing at the start, with `offset` being modifyable at any time.

Comment: So you want to pretend as if the sound started at some variable amount of time? So if you had an offset of `2000` then `snd.seek(1000)` should move the play position to `3000`ms?

Comment: Here's the scenario:
1. I set `offset` to `5000`.
2. I do `seek(1000)`
3. I do `play()`
At this point, there should be a whole 4000ms left of silence before the actual sound starts. If I do `pause()` 1000ms after play, and then call `play()` again, there should be 3000ms left of silence, etc.

Comment: Ohhh, I finally understand! So you want to _add_ some seconds of silence to the start of a sound so that it starts _later_ than it otherwise would. I'll see if I can answer you now :)

Comment: Yes exactly ! And the offset needs to be modifyable in the sense that if the offset is 5000 and the current seek position is something like 8000 (so 3 seconds in the actual sound), and I change the offset to 4000, then since the seek remains at 8000, it means we're now 4 seconds into the sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Howl does not appear to support this, but you can wrap an instance of howl and add this logic yourself. You could create a new class that inherits from `Howl` with this logic included.

And it's not going to be trivial.

This example is woefully incomplete, but it illustrates an approach that might work. You'll basically want to overload every method in your subclass and make it offset aware.

```
import { Howl, HowlOptions } from 'howler'

interface HowlWithOffsetOptions extends HowlOptions {
    offset: number
}

class HowlWithOffset extends Howl {
    #offset: number = 0

    constructor(options: HowlWithOffsetOptions) {
        super(options)
        this.#offset = options.offset
    }

    offset(newOffset?: number): number {
        if (newOffset) {
            this.#offset = newOffset
        }
        return this.#offset
    }
    
    // start playing in `offset` milliseconds.
    play() {
        setTimeout(() => super.play(), this.#offset)
    }

    seek(position?: number): number {
        if (position != null) {
            if (position > this.#offset) {
                super.seek(this.#offset - position)
            } else {
                super.seek(0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, those implementations are incomplete. You'd need to handle the case where you seek to a value less than the offset, you probably need to keep track of whether you're in the offset part or the actual sound part. You may need to call `seek(newPosition)` when you change the offset if you to support changing the offset while it's playing.

But in theory, you should be able to override each method in way that is offset aware.

Good luck!

Comment: I will try something like that, but I'm suspicious about the accuracy of `setTimeout`

Comment: How accurate do you need it to be? It's true that it may fire a few milliseconds late, but the alternative is blocking the main thread with a loop like `while (isItTimeYet()) {}; this.play()` which is a pretty bad idea for lots of reasons.

Comment: I cannot afford more than 1-2ms at max. I have visuals tied to the audio position.

Comment: 60 frames per second is 16ms per frame. And as long as you aren't blocking the main thread the timeout should usually fire no more than 5ms after you want it to. But even if it did, when the timeout eventually fires you could `seek()` to ahead a tiny bit to make up for it. Save the time when it's supposed to start, then when the timeout fires `snd.seek(Date.now() - scheduledStartTime)`. If it fires 100 ms late, then you just jump 100ms ahead. Without using the [Web Audio API directly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), I think this is the best you can do.